# Bash - dirname: missing operand

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

My pipeline fetches the directory of a `terragrunt.hcl` file and run a bunch of test against it. I want my bash to execute 2 commands if my `if` statement is true, if not true jump to the `else` statement and my `else` should be do nothing and exit.
This bash below actually works but I get this error below in the pipeline logs whenever a `terragrunt.hcl` is not touched. I am assuming something if off on my `if` statement!

here is my bash :

```
#!/bin/bash

if find . -name "terragrunt.hcl" -print0 | xargs -0 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA ; then # output only latest terragrunt.hcl commit
   find . -name "terragrunt.hcl" -print0 | xargs -0 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq # command 1
   for i in $(find . -name "terragrunt.hcl" -print0 | xargs -0 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq); do cd /usr/bin/regula/bin && ./regula /path/to/$i /usr/bin/regula/lib /path/to/custom-rules; done # command 2
else 
   :
fi
```

Here is the error:

```
$ ./compliance_check.sh
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

Please help!!!

Comment: BTW, consider scoping your `cd` to a subshell. f/e, that might look like `(cd /usr/bin/regula/bin && exec ./regula /path/to/"$i" /usr/bin/regula/lib /path/to/custom-rules)` -- the `exec` consumes the subshell created by the `(` so there's no performance impact, and the fact that you have the `cd` done in your subshell means it doesn't change the directory the rest of your script is in.

Comment: Also, `for i in $(anything)` is bad form; see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). See instead the "Actions" and "Complex Actions" sections of [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind). And you might store the output of your first `find` so you don't need to rerun it inside the `if` block. At a glance, it looks like there's additional room to avoid duplicate work as well.

Comment: ...alternately, if you exist there to only be one file under that name, it's probably better to handle the case where that expectation is broken explicitly; that way, code past the handler can be secure that the assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `xargs` to ever run `dirname` with an empty argument list, and it's the GNU version, make it:

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty -n 1 dirname
```

...for that pipeline element.

(Also, consider using `-d $'\n'` to suppress some of the more unfortunate behavior that xargs has out-of-the-box when you don't use `-0`).

---

An alternate implementation that does less duplicative work might look something vaguely like the following code (completely untested since the question uses tools and directory structures that aren't accessible/testable by others):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A dirnames=( )
readarray -d '' -t targetFiles < <(find . -name "terragrunt.hcl" -print0)
for file in "${targetFiles[@]}"; do
  readarray -t changedFileNames < <(
    git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$CI_COMMIT_SHA" "$file"
  )
  for changedFileName in "${changedFileNames[@]}"; do
    dirnames[${changedFileName%/*}]=1
  done
done
for dirname in "${!dirnames[@]}"; do
  (cd /usr/bin/regula/bin && exec ./regula /path/to/"$dirname" /usr/bin/regula/lib /path/to/custom-rules)
done
```

Comment: `xargs --no-run-if-empty -n 1 dirname` was the missing peace. After I injected that part in the bash the error was gone :)... Yes I totally agree that are so many different ways to make this cleaner :). I took notes of all pointers!! blessings all that was top helpful!!!!